# Location of original assembly(not the current executing)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, build, path

Suppose I have a solution which contains 4 projects, A, A_UnitTests, B, and B_UnitTests.

Project A has a data file, which is added as a link to A_UnitTests and set to copy to the output directory. When unit tests are run or when the code is executed in production, the path to that file is correctly identified using the following code snippet:

```
public static string GetFullPath(string relativePath)
{
    string retVal = string.Empty;
    if (System.Web.HttpContext.Current == null)
    {
        string locationBeforeShadowCopy = typeof(A.SomeClassInA).Assembly.CodeBase;
        UriBuilder uri = new UriBuilder(locationBeforeShadowCopy);
        string locationWithoutUriPrefixes = Uri.UnescapeDataString(uri.Path);
        string dir = Path.GetDirectoryName(locationWithoutUriPrefixes);
        retVal = Path.Combine(dir, relativePath);
    }
    else
    {
        // stuff that doesn't matter
    }

    return retVal;
}
```

However, I have a new testcase in B_UnitTests which attempts to use this code path to find the file location. However, even though I call `typeof(A.SomeClassInA).Assembly.CodeBase`, it is being called from B_UnitTests, using its referenced DLLs. This means the path return is the B_UnitTests output directory + a relative path. So it doesn't find the data file.

Without resorting to hard coded settings and build scripts, what could I use to specify the correct path?

**Update (clarification)**
The real issue is with typeForClassInA.Assembly.CodeBase returning the path of the executing assembly rather than A itself. It seems very wrong to provide a type that comes from some assembly but instead of returning the original assembly location, it returns the path to the executing assembly which happens to have a reference to it.

Comment: don't understand the question. what's the relationship between project `B_UnitTests` and the project `A`? The data file is in project A, and it is also used in `B_UnitTests`?

Comment: Have you considered using the same approach that A_Unit Tests did, of including a link to it from B_UnitTests?

Comment: @Richardissimo right, that is definitely an option. But for the sake of other people who might come across this question later, the real issue is with typeForClassInA.Assembly.CodeBase returning the path of the executing assembly rather than A itself. It seems very wrong to provide a type that comes from some assembly but instead of returning the original assembly location, it returns the path to the executing assembly which happens to have a reference to it. Is there any obvious solution to this problem or is this expectation not feasible?

Comment: If there is a reference to 'typeForClassInA', then its assembly will be being copied into the output directory of the other project, which is why CodeBase is (correctly) pointing there, because that's where it's being loaded from. I admit that I avoid using Shadow Copy to avoid exactly these kinds of problems. I have a method which goes "up" from the assembly's location to the solution's location; and my relative paths are 'rooted' at that folder.

Comment: @Richardissimo "[…]because that's where it's being loaded from" Ok, that's what I feared. I think we can say that this question has no clean solution and your comment is the correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is a reference to 'typeForClassInA', then its assembly will be being copied into the output directory of B_UnitTests. So when you ask for CodeBase of that type's assembly from a test in B_UnitTests, it is (correctly) pointing at the version of assembly A in the B_UnitTests output folder, because that's where it's being loaded from.

I admit that I avoid using Shadow Copy to avoid exactly these kinds of problems of locating resources which are alongside the assembly, since ShadowCopy doesn't understand that they are needed, and they don't get shadow copied.

Another thing which can help is to build all the projects into the same output folder by changing all the project output folders to be "..\bin". For example, this would mean that A_UnitTests would not need the link to the resource file (once shadow copy is off).

I have a method similar to the one you've shown which goes "up" from the assembly's location (which for me is the shared bin folder) to the solution's location; and my relative paths are 'rooted' at that folder.

If that all sounds too complex, you could just use the same approach that A_UnitTests did, of including a link to it from B_UnitTests.